# Username turns into link to user profile Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

****added user views profile in the url.py section plus my users view.py ***

Hey guys I tried asking this a few times but don't think I was thorough enough now I have tried so many different ways in the last few days was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction. I want usernames used in the post.post to turn into links for that users profile. right now this is the output I am getting.

[link to what my post.post looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gN64v.jpg)

as you can see I get the username in the post but its does not show as a link to that users profile it just shows as plain text I would like for @devil to be a link to the users profile ... in the back end though the system does find that @devil is a user in the database it just doesn't show it as a link in my front end template

This is my views.py I am using so that the back end finds any user in the post.post

```
def get(self, request):
        form = HomeForm()
        posts = Status1.objects.filter(user=request.user).order_by('-id')
        users = User.objects.all()
        args = {'form':form, 'posts':posts, 'users':users}

        return render(request, self.template_name, args)

    def post(self, request):
        form = HomeForm(request.POST)
        users = User.objects.all()
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.user = request.user
            post.save()
            for username in post.post.split():
                if username.startswith("@"):
                    user = User.objects.get(username=username)
                    username = user
                    print(username) #THIS PRINTS THE USERNAME IN THE TERMINAL SO THAT I KNOW IT'S PARSING THE POST FOR USERS MENTIONED IN THE POST WHEN SUBMITTED 

            text = form.cleaned_data['post']
            form = HomeForm()
            return redirect('home')


        context = {'form': form, 'text': text, 'users':users, 'username':username}
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

This is the frond end template I am using to show the information as pictured above for the post.post. I'm not sure how I go about telling the template that any username starting with @ should be a link to the users profile since it's grabbing the post.post information from the database.

```
  {% for post in posts %}
         {{ post.post}}
  {% endfor %}
```

This is my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Status1(models.Model):
    post = models.CharField(max_length=333)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    blockchain = models.TextField()
```

and this is my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
    #path('', HomeView, name='home'),
    path('register/', user_views.register, name='register'),
    path('profile/', user_views.profile, name='profile'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='users/logout.html'), name='logout'),
]
```

this is my views.py for users

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f'Welcome {username}!') 
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form})

def profile(request):
    return render(request, 'users/profile.html')
```

I have been banging my head over this I can't figure it out thank you so much for anyone that helps

Comment: In your urls.py I dont see anything that looks like a user profile view. Where should the link point to?

Comment: I see so I need to add that in the url first before I continue? Thank you

Comment: Yes, because you need the rout and the handler to link to somewhere.

Comment: ok thank you @Charnel will get that done first your a life save I couldn't figure this out for the life of me I was so lost at least now I have direction

Comment: @Charnel I added my user profile views and url any idea where I go from here? Thank you

Comment: Now you need to specify which profile you will be seeing by modifying URL patter to `path('profile/(?P<object_id>\d+)/$'` and then you can put something like this in template `<a href="{% url 'profile' user.id %}">user profile</a>`

Comment: obviously, inside `profile` you need to handle the requests asking for specific user ID.

Comment: Hey @charnel I got the url set up but this still isn't giving me the desired result this is my latest question I went into more details with the set up I have now https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59926405/post-is-searched-for-users-in-user-database-and-turned-into-profile-link-with-or thank you for all your help I feel like I'm so close now thanks to you